# arc4random() range including negatives

Tags: arc4random

Looking to find how I would format a call to `arc4Random()` to use a range of numbers from -10 to 10.

Or does `arc4Random()` only generate from 0 to X? If that's the case I will need to manipulate the result from `arc4Random()` so that it may be a result within the specified range?

Comment: A [useful reference](http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-03-18-random-numbers.html) for random numbers in Cocoa

Answer (score 6):

`arc4random` returns a `u_int32_t`, which is an unsigned type.  You need to cast it to a signed type and then subtract.

I assume you want a number from -10 to +10 inclusive (you want both -10 and +10 to be chosen sometimes).

If you are targetting iOS 4.3 or later, or Mac OS X 10.7 or later, you should use the `arc4random_uniform` function:

```
int myNumber = (int)arc4random_uniform(21) - 10;
```

If you are targetting an older OS, you have to use `arc4random`:

```
int myNumber = (int)(arc4random() % 21) - 10;
```

Comment: What's the difference between arc4random and arc4random_uniform? What does the number 21 represent? What does the number 10 represent?

Comment: You can read about the difference between the functions by typing `man arc4random`.  The 21 and the 10 are derived from the range of numbers you specified in your question.

Comment: Specifically, the 21 is `upperBound - lowerBound + 1`, and the 10 is `-lowerBound`. Alternatively, you're adding `lowerBound` instead of subtracting `-lowerBound`. In the question, `upperBound` is +10 and `lowerBound` is -10.